# accordion из bootstrap 4.1 примера

Tags: bootstrap4

Всем привет,

Я использовал accordion из этого примера
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/#accordion-example

Не подскажите а как сделать чтобы заголовок открытого элементы выделялся (например в strong).
Я вижу что aria-expanded - свойство открыт блок или нет но как его увязать со свойствами текста заголовка - непонятно...

jquery3.1/vuejs 2.5

2) И можно ли эти блоки открыть/закрывать програмно ?

EDITED:

В своем vuejs темплейты делаю:

```
<template>
    <div class="card offset-md-1">


        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" v-show="logged_user_id && logged_user_name">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    :aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" id="myCollapsible">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                ...

<script>
    export default {

        data() {
            return {
                logged_user_id: '',
            }
        },

        created() {
        },

        mounted() {

            $('#myCollapsible').on('hide.bs.collapse', function (e) {
                alert( "myCollapsible hide.bs.collapse::"+(-99) )   // ЭТОТ АЛЕРТ НЕ ВЫСКАКИВАЕТ - ТО ЕСТЬ СОБЫТИЕ НЕ ВЫЗЫВАЕТСЯ
                // во время закрытия
                console.log(e.target)  // цель по которой кликаем ( тут тебе и стили задать можно)
            })

            $('#myCollapsible').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
                // во время открытия
                alert( "myCollapsible show.bs.collapse::"+(-88) )  // ЭТОТ АЛЕРТ НЕ ВЫСКАКИВАЕТ - ТО ЕСТЬ СОБЫТИЕ НЕ ВЫЗЫВАЕТСЯ
                console.log(e.target)   // цель по которой кликаем ( тут тебе и стили задать можно)
            })
            alert( "created AFTER!::"+(-6) )  // ЭТОТ АЛЕРТ ВЫСКАКИВАЕТ - ТО ЕСТЬ СОБЫТИЕ MOUNTED ВЫЗЫВАЕТСЯ БЕЗ ОШИБОК В КОНСОЛЕ
            ...
        },
```

И обработчики событий выше не вызываются при клике на кнопке navbar-а...
Если вставить в событие created - также не работает.

id задан как myCollapsible - только для моего navbar-а - иыми словами он единственный

```
Vue :2.5.16
jQuery :3.3.1
```

А как правильно ?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Вот так отследить можно:

```
$('#myCollapsible').on('hide.bs.collapse', function (e) {
  // во время закрытия 
  console.log(e.target)  // цель по которой кликаем ( тут тебе и стили задать можно)
})

$('#myCollapsible').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
  // во время открытия
  console.log(e.target)   // цель по которой кликаем ( тут тебе и стили задать можно)
})
```